# How to upload videos to YouTube [Xamarin.Forms (Portable) ]

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to upload videos to `YouTube` but somehow it's not working in `Xamarin.Forms (Portable)` project. Is there any way to upload the Videos in `YouTube` through `Xamarin.Forms (Portable)`

```
var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = Constants.API.Google.ClientID,
        ClientSecret = Constants.API.Google.ClientSecret
    },
    Scopes = new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube }
};
var flow = new AuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer);
TokenResponse token = flow.LoadTokenAsync("user", CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

but every time I am getting null in `TokenResponse token`, I am not sure what should I pass in place of `user` in `flow.LoadTokenAsync("user", CancellationToken.None)`

Thank You.

Comment: I suggest you post this as an issue on the client library.   https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had feared the Google .Net client library does not currently support Xamarin.  Please see issue: [Unable to Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices in Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/924)

> It's because GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker requires several classes from Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices, and Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices is not compatible with Xamarin.

Comment: So, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Not using the official client library.  Your going to have to code this on your own.  Chris's recommendation will not work as the YouTube API does not support service accounts.

Comment: So, You mean to say, I have to use the HttpClient, right?

Comment: your going to have to build all of the calls yourself You cant use the client library yes.   This should work you though the Oauth flow part at least.   http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: You should open a new question your original question was answered by changing this question it won't help others.